# exit for loop with echo

Tags: php, for-loop

The following PHP code is working as expected. I need to echo "copy error" message when the code is unable to execute the command in 4 attempts.

```
for($num_tries = 0 ; $num_tries < 4 ; $num_tries++)
{
    $cloudcmd = "cp abc xyz ";
    system($cloudcmd,$status);
    if($status != 0)
    {
        sleep(3) ;
        continue ;
    }
    break ;
}
```

I tried to add echo command after break; but it does not seem to work.

Comment: after break , the statement wont execute

Comment: The whole point of `break` is that it exits the loop. The execution will never reach the line immediately after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly, you don't need to introduce additional variables and checks to do this.

Keeping it simple, you can inspect the value of the for loop variable $num_tries once outside the for loop:

```
if($num_tries==4)....
```

You also have the $status variable available after the for loop.

```
if($status!=0)....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$success = false;
for($num_tries = 0 ; $num_tries < 4 ; $num_tries++)
        {
        $cloudcmd = "cp abc xyz ";
        system($cloudcmd,$status);
        if($status != 0)
            {
            sleep(3) ;
            continue ;
            }
    $success=true;
    break ;
    }
if($success)
    {
    //do your thing
    }
```

Comment: Why the variable? Can't you just put the code before `break` (in place of `$success=true;`)?

Comment: That's the way I like to program. That way I can reuse the variable even further in the code if I need to give some kind of feedback multiple times if a thing has succeeded.

Comment: Why not use the status variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
for ($num_tries=0;$num_tries < 4;$num_tries++)
{
    system('cp abc xyz',$status);
    if ($status === 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    sleep(3);
}
if ($status !== 0)
{
    echo 'error';
}
```

This loop will break as soon as `$status` is 0, meaning the `system()` call was a success, after the loop, the `$status` value will be accessible, still (PHP doesn't have block scope), so check it's value and echo if needed. You can easily replace the `echo` statement using an `exit()`, to stop the rest of the script.

Comment: I need some sleep, forget the `fundamental flaw` I mentioned, edited it out, for some reason I seem to have overlooked the `continue;` statement. Still, I feel my suggestion is a valid, and -IMO- a more elegant approach

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
for($num_tries = 1 ; $num_tries <=4 ; $num_tries++){  
    $cloudcmd = "cp abc xyz ";  
    system($cloudcmd,$status);  
    if($status != 0) {  
       if($num_tries!=4){  
         sleep(3);  
         continue;  
       } else {  
         echo "error";  
       }  
    }                               
    break;  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `break` statement causes the loop to break, and any code that occurs after the break, within the loop is skipped over.

Perhaps, you could do something like this:

```
$success = false;

for($num_tries = 0 ; $num_tries < 4 ; $num_tries++) {

    if (success()) {
        // do something
        $success = true;
    }
}

echo ($success) ? 'Success' : 'Failure';
```